# Can't set 2K resolution on two external monitors simultaneously

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, wayland

I'm using two 2K iiyama monitors that support daisy chaining. Laptop is connected to first monitor using USB-C. Monitors are connected using Display Port. All cables are provided by manufacturer. When I'm setting up resolution of both to 2K, it looks like number of pixels is increasing but they cannot fit into screen properly, they protrude beyond screen. Can't lower scale anymore as I'm using 100%. It is possible to set 2K successfully but only on one monitor, the second needs to have super small resolution. Is there any way to fix this issue?

- Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 2
- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7
- Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
- iiyama ProLite XUB2792QSN-B1